# A cubefree-preserving morphism from 5 to 2?

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

A word is cubefree if it cannot be written as $xyyyz$ where $y$ has positive length.

Let $h$ be the morphism from $\{0,1,2,3,4\}^*$ to $\{0,1\}^*$ given for words of length 1 as follows ($a\to h(a)$):
$$0\to 001001010011$$
$$1\to 001001101011$$
$$2\to 001010011011$$
$$3\to 001101001011$$
$$4\to 010011001011$$
and extending to longer words by the morphism property $h(xy)=h(x)h(y)$.

Is it cubefree-preserving? That is, if $x$ is cubefree then is $h(x)$ cubefree?

(I checked that it is so for $x$ of length at most 8; in general there is no finite test set by a result of Richomme and Wlazinski, but maybe there's something special about this case.)

And if not this map...

> does there exist *any* cubefree-preserving map from an alphabet of size 5 to an alphabet of size 2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An $\infty$ to 2 (hence 5 to 2) cube-free morphism was constructed by Bean-Ehrenfeucht-McNulty. The fact that your morphism is cube-free follows from their theorem. See Theorem 2.4.1 of my book "Combinatorial Algebra:syntax and semantics".

Comment: Couldn't ask for more!

Comment: Another construction for such a morphism can be found in Theorem 6 of F.-J. Brandenburg, Uniformly growing k-th power-free homomorphisms, Theoret. Comput. Sci. 23 (1893), 69-82.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be hard to prove that your morphism is cube-free.  Basically you have to check that for all letters $a,b,c$ you can't find an occurrence of $h(c)$ in $h(ab)$, except as a prefix or suffix, and further, if $h(a)=st$, $h(b)=uv$, and $h(c)=sv$, then either $a=c$ or $b=c$.  If that holds then a standard argument shows that $h$ is cube-free.  For example, see some of the proofs in N. Rampersad, J. Shallit, M.-w. Wang, "Avoiding large squares in infinite binary words", Theoret. Comput. Sci. 339 (2005), 19-34.